# Is there a way to play different audio files without calling them each with their own function?

Tags: java, android

I have 8 audio files that I need to play when a button is pressed.

Currently, these files are played using a class.  In this class, each audio file has it's own function that plays and pauses each audio file.

Is there a way to do this without repeating the same function for different audio files?

The button in question is connected to an Adafruit feather - essentially if the button is pressed the phone knows to play whichever audio is required.

Here's some code:

Here's what I have so far:

```java
public class Audio {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    boolean paused = false;

    public void playSound_1(Context context) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.Sound_1);
            mp.start();
        }

    public void playSound_2(Context context) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.Sound_2);
            mp.start();
        }

    public void playSound_3(Context context) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.Sound_3);
            mp.start();
        }

}
```

In my fragment I then call the function for each sound:

```java
if (data_check.contains("Sound_1"){
                    audio.playSound_1(this.getContext());
            }

else if (data_check.contains("Sound_2"){
                    audio.playSound_2(this.getContext());
            }
```

The current results are that if the button is pressed (and `data_check` finds the name of the Sound) that sound plays.

What I'd like to do is have the same results but without having `public void playSound_1, 2, 3, 4... etc.`

Comment: First-  don't create multiple media players.  You should create one at most per Activity.  These are heavy objects, they should be reused.  Second-  do you not know how to pass arguments to a function?

Comment: Thanks for this.  How do you suggest I avoid creating multiple players?  

I'm clearly missing something regarding your second comment, so I'll entertain you by saying: no.